# Adding values of cells in different excel file

Tags: excel

I am adding the values of the same cells but from 2 (or more) different Excel files, using this formula:

```
='E:\NCD INTEGRATED MONITORING\2019\[NCD Monitoring Tool 2019 (1st Quarter).xlsx]TOTALS'!$C$11+'E:\NCD INTEGRATED MONITORING\2019\[NCD Monitoring Tool 2019 (2nd Quarter).xlsx]TOTALS'!$C$11
```

I need to change the last part of the formula so that it will automatically get the current cell row number and use it as a cell row number locator to another Excel file. I want to achieve something like this:

```
='E:\NCD INTEGRATED MONITORING\2019\[NCD Monitoring Tool 2019 (1st Quarter).xlsx]TOTALS'!$C$(ROW())+'E:\NCD INTEGRATED MONITORING\2019\[NCD Monitoring Tool 2019 (2nd Quarter).xlsx]TOTALS'!$C$(ROW())
```

Can someone help me? I've searched it on google but I was unsuccessful. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that by using `INDEX` formula. This solution is recommended as other proposed functions might not be suitable if your file is already big or slow (`INDIRECT` or `ADDRESS` are both **volatile** functions).

The general syntax looks like that:

```
=INDEX($C:$C,ROW())+INDEX($C:$C,ROW())
```

[image]

In your case you'd need to use:

```
=INDEX('E:\NCD INTEGRATED MONITORING\2019\[NCD Monitoring Tool 2019 (1st Quarter).xlsx]TOTALS'!$C:$C,ROW())+INDEX('E:\NCD INTEGRATED MONITORING\2019\[NCD Monitoring Tool 2019 (2nd Quarter).xlsx]TOTALS'!$C:$C,ROW())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by using the two functions `INDIRECT` and `ADDRESS`

The address function takes row number, column number and sheet name as input to create a cell address. Indirect can then be used to create the reference base on the cell address.

Address takes the following input:

```
=ADDRESS (row_num, col_num, [abs_num], [a1], [sheet])
```

As an example to get you started it could be used something like:

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(some row number, 3, 1, 1, "E:\NCD INTEGRATED MONITORING\2019[NCD Monitoring Tool 2019 (1st Quarter).xlsx]TOTALS"))
```

Of cource remember to input the desired row number. Using for example `=Row()`